# What kind of 40pin connector is this?

Tags: identification, connector, camera

I'm looking for a cable that connects an Insta360 One RS 1-inch camera module (lens) with it's computing unit (core). They use these 40pin connectors:

[image: Insta360 One RS connector male]

[image: Insta360 One RS connector female]

Any idea what kind of connectors these are?

I have a hard time to figure it out (and Insta360 is not helping). It's none of the various standard camera interface connectors (CameraLink, …), neither PCIe, OCuLink, SCSI, etc. – even though some of these look really similar.
Neither Google nor Bing reverse image search helped.

Answer (score 3):

That appears to be a TE CHAMP series docking connector.

https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-2129261-1.html

https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data+Sheet%7F6-1773457-9_CHAMP_DOCKING_CONNECTOR%7F0711%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_6-1773457-9_CHAMP_DOCKING_CONNECTOR_0711.pdf%7F2129261-1

Comment: Wow, awesome! That looks exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!
I'll order some to confirm and will of course accept the answer then.

Comment: @orzechow Please accept the answer by clicking the green checkmark